# Upgrade Shibboleth to newest version on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shibboleth

I have an Ubuntu (12.04.4 LTS) web server running Shibboleth 2.4.3

I think Shibboleth was installed using apt-get

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep shib
libapache2-mod-shib2        install
libshibsp5                  install
shibboleth-sp2-schemas      install
```

I'd like to upgrade to Shibboleth 2.5.3 but apt-get is telling me that I've already got the latest version. But I dont, not by a long shot!!

Any advice please?

---

Some extra output after running apt-get update as asked for

```
apt-cache show libapache2-mod-shib2
Package: libapache2-mod-shib2
Priority: extra
Section: universe/web
Installed-Size: 826
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Shib Team <pkg-shibboleth-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: shibboleth-sp2
Version: 2.4.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), liblog4cpp5, libmemcached6 (>= 0.44), libodbc1 (>= 2.2.11) | unixodbc (>= 2.2.11), libsaml7, libshibsp5, libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libxerces-c3.1, libxmltooling5, adduser
Recommends: apache2, openssl
Conflicts: libapache2-mod-shib
Filename: pool/universe/s/shibboleth-sp2/libapache2-mod-shib2_2.4.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size: 254496
MD5sum: 72c2d318e6da4f163ea540c43dec64a9
SHA1: e8a29a347540aceba23db65783663f8e05c860ae
SHA256: f0bc6495d3e2ecdadeb4019bba969aef166105500a6b372640a6546d65b11346
Description-en: Federated web single sign-on system (Apache module)
The Shibboleth System is a standards based software package for web
single sign-on across or within organizational boundaries.  It supports
authorization and attribute exchange using the OASIS SAML 2.0 protocol.
Shibboleth allows sites to make informed authorization decisions for
individual access of protected online resources while allowing users to
establish their identities with their local authentication systems.
.
This package contains the Shibboleth Apache module for service providers
(web servers providing resources protected by Shibboleth) and the
supporting shibd daemon.
Homepage: http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/
Description-md5: 1b4d36e9224597e639627488183ac5dc
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

***EDIT*** 2.5.2 would also be okay to upgrade to

Answer (score 4):

Switch.ch provides a repository with Shibboleth 2.5 for ubuntu 12.04 users, here: https://www.switch.ch/aai/docs/shibboleth/SWITCH/2.5/sp/deployment/?os=ubuntu
You should be able to add their repository and download shibboleth 2.5 by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove libshibsp5
sudo curl -k -O http://pkg.switch.ch/switchaai/SWITCHaai-swdistrib.asc
gpg --with-fingerprint  SWITCHaai-swdistrib.asc
sudo apt-key add SWITCHaai-swdistrib.asc
echo 'deb http://pkg.switch.ch/switchaai/ubuntu precise main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/SWITCHaai-swdistrib.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get install shibboleth
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/shibboleth
sudo chown _shibd:_shibd /var/run/shibboleth
sudo service shibd restart
```

Comment: I had to run `apt-get update` just before the install step.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm what version your apt repository has by running the following:

```
apt-get update

apt-cache show packagename
```

Comment: Added some console output

Comment: It looks like the 12.04 repo doesn't have the most up to date version. From one of my 12.04 hosts the current version is 2.4.3. From my 14.04 host its 2.5.2.

Comment: Ah, okay. Is there a way to direct Ubuntu at the newer repo?

Comment: With little research, your probably better off upgrading to 14.04 and then upgrading this package. I can't seem to locate a v2.5.2 package for 12.04. You could possible try grabbing the debs from the 14.04 repo and installing it with dpkg but I would suggest highly against doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This server is actually due to be replaced. I think my answer is to bring it up the schedule :)